# c++ doubly linked list search and remove

Tags: c++

I'm having trouble looking for a node in my list and then deleting it. I've tried so many ways but this is my code so far. I don't know if the problem is in my insert or maybe in my display function? I"m barely learning this.

```
void removeStudent(int id)
{
    node *trash = NULL;

    node *current = head;
    while ( current!= NULL)
    {
        if ( current->data.id == id)
        {
            trash = current;
            current->prev->next = current->next;
            current->next->prev = current->prev;
            delete trash;


        }
    }


}
```

this is my insert function

```
    void push(student s)
{

    node *tmp = new node;
    tmp->data = s;
    tmp->next = head;
    tmp->prev = NULL;

    if (head == NULL)
    {
        head = tmp;
        tail = tmp;
    }
    else
    {
        head->prev = tmp;
        head = tmp;
    }

}
```

and this is my display function

```
void display()
{
    node *current = head;

    while (current!=NULL)
    {
        cout << current->data.name << endl;
        cout << current->data.GPA << endl;
        cout << current->data.id << endl;
        cout << current->data.university << endl;
        current = current->next;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why `node *trash = new node;`? This will leak memory.

Comment: You must address the special cases of a node at the beginning or end (or both) of the list. Is that hint sufficient?

Comment: `I've tried so many ways`  There should be only one way, and it is the way you wrote down or drew on paper.  When you have an assignment such as this, it pays to draw boxes and lines to denote the nodes and links.  Then you see what needs to be done to make the middle node unlink and link the two remaining nodes together.  Then you write the code to simulate what you wrote on the paper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following. I suppose that your class contains also data member tail.

```
void removeStudent( int id )
{
    node *current = head;

    while ( current != NULL && current->data.id != id ) current = current->next;

    if ( current != NULL )
    {
       if ( current->prev != NULL ) current->prev->next = current->next;
       else head = current->next;

       if ( current->next != NULL ) current->next->prev = current->prev;
       else  tail = current->prev;

       delete current;
    }
}
```

If your class has no data member tail then you have to remove statement

```
       else  tail = current->prev;
```

from the function body.

Answer (score 0):

```
node *trash = new node;
trash = current;
```

memory leak, because you are loosing the memory allocate by newin first line and you do not keep a pointer to that memory. You assign the pointer `trash` the `current` one.

You should just do that:

```
node *trash = NULL; // declare a pointer and set it to NULL
```

HINT:

When dealing with list, in order to test your code use a paper and a pencil, create a small list and run in the paper the cases of modifying (here deleting) a node from the start and the end of the list.

Also, what happens when the list has only one node and what happens when it is empty.

Answer (score 0):

`current = current->next;` at the end of the loop?

Comment: I Forgot that :( but i just added it and it gave me an error on this line                                          current->next->prev = current->prev;

Comment: You have to check that current->next exist before assigning current->next->prev and vise versa, otherwise you'll have predictable problems with front&back nodes deletion